# Ruby on Railsで検索機能を実装したらtext/htmlがない、というエラーが出る

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

検索フォームから検索を行うときに以下の写真のようなエラーがでます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (SearchsController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["text/html"]
request.variant: []

NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot.):
```

ターミナルを見るとapp/views/blog/index.html.erbがないように書かれていますが、routeもviewも設定してあると思います。何か他に不足しているのでしょうか。
ご教授願いただけたら幸いです。
何卒宜しくお願い致します。

以下画像投稿のコードとファイル（同じ内容）

```
rails g model Search name:string
rake db:migrate
```

---

search.rb

```
class Search < ApplicationRecord
    def self.search(search) #self.でクラスメソッドとしている
        if search # Controllerから渡されたパラメータが!= nilの場合は、titleカラムを部分一致検索
          Search.where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
        else
          Search.all #全て表示。
        end
    end
end
```

---

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag searchs_path, :method => 'get' do %> 
                      <p>
                        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
                        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
                      </p>
                    <% end %>
<%= yield %>
```

---

routes.rb

```
　　#get 'searchs/index'
　　#get "blog/index" => "searchs#index"
resources:searchs
```

---

searchscontroller.rb

```
class SearchsController < ApplicationController

    def index
    #ViewのFormで取得したパラメータをモデルに渡す
        @projects = Search.search(params[:search])
    end
end
```

[image: search.rbのモデルファイル作成]
[image: index.html.erbに検索フォーム設置]
[image: routes.rb]
[image: searchs_controller.rb]

Comment: 画像ではなくコードを質問文に書いた方が良い回答が付くと思いますよ。コード見るのでめんどくさかったら誰も回答しようと思わないでしょう？

Comment: 文字の情報を画像にしてしまうと検索や引用が難しくなるのが問題です。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/122530

Comment: そもそも一枚目の画像から間違えていました。コード書きましたのでもし分かることがあればご回答宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 質問中の `app/views/blog/index.html.erb` は `app/views/searchs/index.html.erb` の間違いだと思いますが、
このファイルはは本当に存在しますか? 質問文からそれが確認できません。

Answer (score 1):

> SearchsController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant.

というエラーなので、

> app/views/blog/index.html.erbがない

ではなく app/views/searches/index.html.erb が必要なのでは? あるいは、 render メソッドに BlogController#index のテンプレートを使うように明示。